# Top menu bar cutting short on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, positioning

Hoping you can help with an odd issue.

www.thetraderally.com works fine on a computer and largely fine on my mobile (Samsung Galaxy S3) but oddly does the following:

1) Loads about 80% of the width of the central content. Not an issue per se as it lets you scroll across to view content but would be better if it loaded 100%.

2) When you scroll the remaining 20% of the dark grey menu bar (and light grey / red strips immediately underneath) aren't visible. The links on them are but because the font is white they don't show.

CSS and HTML viewable through the source code... have tried targeting mobile in CSS and it works, to an extent.

Hoping someone can help me! :)

Thanks in advance

Natasha

Comment: Could it possibly be your web browser settings to auto-fit content?

Comment: Nope, tried that. Have played around with the width and whatever I do it cuts off the dark grey bit but nothing else.